# php sessions not passing on iframe safari

Tags: php, session, safari

I have created a booking system where users select the date (or dates they want to book on an availability chart, click Book, then go to the next page "Booking Page" to fill in their details.  When they tick the date on the availability page the date or dates are put into a session that is picked up on the next page(Booking page).

People can add this system into a page on their own websites  using an iframe.  This worked really well, but recently people using safari (mac,ipad) select the date, click Book, but when they they are taken to the booking page are told that no day has been selected. I can't understand why when I test it on my pc using safari and my ipad it works fine.  But this has now been reported by several people that they can't book a date.

I have read that this is something that safari has done for security reasons.

I have tried adding this:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');
```

Can anyone please advise on how I can overcome this problem, preferably without having to ask all the people using it to add code to the page.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iframe, cross-domain cookies, p3p policy, and safari with error: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125741/iframe-cross-domain-cookies-p3p-policy-and-safari-with-error-a-required-anti)

Comment: Wild speculation because you haven't provided a reduced test case: You are using an absolute URI for the iframe so the cookies are breaking because the hostname is changing.