# p3p header not working in chrome/safari

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, safari, p3p

I have a site that uses an SSO solution with another site. It does this by embedding an iFrame in the site for login.

The issue that I am having is that with Chrome and Safari, it does not save the login cookie when 3rd party cookies is disabled.

The site uses ASP.net. I have added the P3P header with a value of CP="CAO PSA OUR" in IIS. Its still not working. Does something else need to be done for Safari and Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

[P3P policies are not supported by most browsers](https://mitraroger.wordpress.com/tag/p3p-policies/) barring Internet Explorer.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)

> Microsoft Internet Explorer is the only major browser to support P3P.

Google Chrome basically [bypasses every OS dependent privacy settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/02/20/google-bypassing-user-privacy-settings/) (and by that I mean policies defined by IE for windows and Safari for Mac).

You can reach out to [Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en) if you need more information about 3rd party cookies.

Safari - you're most likely out of luck. There are workarounds like [Safari 3rd party cookie iframe trick no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930671/safari-3rd-party-cookie-iframe-trick-no-longer-working) and [Iframe, cross-domain cookies, p3p policy, and safari with error: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125741/iframe-cross-domain-cookies-p3p-policy-and-safari-with-error-a-required-anti) but your mileage may vary.